# Matplotlib with mollweide: longitude range?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset that covers the globe, from latitude -90 to +90, and longitude 0 to 360. When I try to plot that with matplotlib in a mollweide projection, half the plot is blank. Apparently mollweide requires the longitudes to be in [-180,180] (actually that but in radians). Is there a simple way to tell mollweide that my data covers [0,360] instead? Currently I have to use `np.roll` to shift the whole data array halfway around, and subtract 180 from the longitude.

Here's a simple test case. In this testcase the `temp` value is zero at longitude 0 (the prime meridian) for ease of visualization. The desired output is to see that blue edge crossing the prime meridian in the middle of the plotted map.

```py
def plot_globe_dataset():
    # Set up the map projection and figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'mollweide'})

    xdim = 200                  # longitude
    ydim = 100                  # latitude
    longitude = np.linspace(0, 360, xdim)
    latitude = np.linspace(-90, 90, ydim)

    temp = np.random.rand(ydim, xdim)
    temp = temp * longitude     # so values increase from 0 to longitude=360

    # Plot the data
    # mollweide requires longitude in radians -pi to pi, latitude in radians -pi/2 to pi/2
    # So we have to rotate the data around the longitude axis, then shift longitude to match
    temp = np.roll(temp, xdim//2, axis=1)
    longitude -= 180

    c = ax.pcolormesh(np.radians(longitude), np.radians(latitude), temp,
                      cmap='coolwarm')

    # Add a colorbar
    plt.colorbar(c, orientation='horizontal', pad=0.05)

    plt.title("test plot")
    plt.show()

plot_globe_dataset()
```